# Bug: routing to index when index doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Admittedly I asked about this a few days ago but I wasn't being clear so I didn't get any proper answers.
So I have this mini-blog thing on my website and I have noticed that if I **enter invalid data** (i.e. title too short) I get **redirected** from x.com/posts/new (or /edit) to index (x.com/posts), despite the fact that post index doesn't exist (**except: index** added in routes).

**posts controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :admin_user, except: [:show]

  def show

  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
    @categories = Category.all.where(belongs_to_posts: true)
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @categories = Category.all.where(belongs_to_posts: true)
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def find_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:description, :title, :image, :categories_id)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root
      ...        
      get 'galleries/accept'              => 'galleries#accept'
      resources :galleries
      resources :photos
      resources :posts,                  except: [:index]
      resources :categories
      resources :documents
    end
```

**_form for posts**

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :image
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :categories_id, :collection => @categories, label_method: :name, value_method: :id
  = f.cktext_area :description, data: {no_turbolink: true}, :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'}
  = f.button :submit
```

It might be worth noting that the index doesn't exist because I display posts on main page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I'd say you should inspect your `rake routes`. One of the things you'd see there is that your `Post#create` action goes to `/posts`, which is the way a RESTful application's route is defined for new resources.

When working with RESTful applications, the action that would be called when working on a resource is largely determined by the HTTPMethod called on the resource.

A `create` action would be triggered by a `POST` request to the `\posts` route, while the `index` would be triggered by a `GET` request to the `\posts` route

```
Cheatsheet:

create => POST to /posts
index => GET to /posts
update => PATCH to /posts/:id
show => GET to /posts/:id
destroy => DELETE to /posts/:id
edit => GET to /posts/:id/edit
new => GET to /posts/new
```

Now you would wonder why does it still show your `posts/new` form on the same page, that is because you called the `render 'new'` method in your `Post#create` action, which is literally saying render the `new` view on this(create) action.

I hope you understand this better now.

Comment: thank you very much, that was very educational! I still don't quite know how to deal with the problem, though. I assume it's about `if @post.save redirect_to @post else render 'new'`, right? how do I fix this?